# Input Boxes to Properly Display in Safari once CSS is applied

Tags: html, css, safari

I always have a problem when making webpages using `input` or `select` boxes in CSS because the focus is mostly making it for FireFox and IE, but for some reason the text inside text boxes/form input objects are usually never properly aligned (line-height).

I'm wondering if there is a common routine for making input boxes look like they do in FireFox and IE, in Safari, because they usually look horrible once you add a touch of CSS to the element.  Trying to balance out the line-height on each browser usually never works out perfectly, is there something i'm missing to make the inputs in all browsers look the same once you style it? (mostly talking about the line-height of the inner text inside the input box).

ie. Is using `em` instead of `px` a better for cross browser compatibility?

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtobeexperiencedexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helps a lot is using some kind of boilerplate starting point, that resets all browsers to the same base CSS (for so far possible). Specifically I've enjoyed [HTML5Reset](http://html5reset.org/), you could just take the [CSS reset file](https://github.com/murtaugh/HTML5-Reset/blob/master/_/css/style.css) and see if it helps you.